# Vagrant running a puppet master with a puppet agent

Tags: puppet, vagrant

I'm using a Vagrantfile that looks like this:

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  config.vm.define :puppet do |c|
    c.vm.host_name = 'puppet.domain.com'
    c.vm.box = "precise64"
    c.vm.network :hostonly, "192.168.33.100"

    c.vm.provision :puppet  # This sets up puppetmaster and puppet configs

    c.vm.provision :puppet_server do |puppet|
      puppet.puppet_server = 'puppet.domain.com'
      puppet.puppet_node = 'puppet.domain.com'
    end
  end
end
```

When they both run on start up, the client never connects to the master, presumably because the master hasn't started listening on the port yet.

How do I get Vagrant to delay the execution of puppet agent? Maybe there's another way of going about it?

Comment: The title of this question would be right at home on Gaming.SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack (ashamed), but in my puppet manifest I've added a sleep:

```
exec { 'wait_for_puppet':
    command => '/bin/sleep 10',
    require => Service['puppetmaster'],
}
```